# Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

Tags: angular

I get that error and I can't find why ... I have the common and form libraries imported into the module .

usuario-edit.component.html

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
<form action="#" *ngIf="usuario">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nombre">Nombre: {{usuario[0].name}}</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre Completo" [(ngModel)]="user_form.nombre" autofocus>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="apellido">Apellido: {{usuario[0].surname}}</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido Completo" [(ngModel)]="user_form.apellido">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="usuario">Usuario: {{usuario[0].usuario}}</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="usuario" placeholder="Escriba un nombre de usuario" [(ngModel)]="user_form.usuario">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pass">Contraseña</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" placeholder="Escriba su nueva contraseña" [(ngModel)]="user_form.pass">
  </div>

  <div class="form-check form-check-inline" *ngFor="let rol of roles">
   <!-- <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="role" value="{{rol}}" (change)="cambiarRol($event)" >  -->
 <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="{{rol}}" name="role"  [(ngModel)]="role" >
    <label class="form-check-label">{{rol.role}}</label>
  </div>
  <div class="container-button">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" (click)="onSave()">Guardar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

usuario.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SharedModule } from 'src/app/shared/shared.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { UsuarioHomeComponent } from './components/usuario-home/usuario-home.component';
import { UsuarioRoutingModule } from './usuario-routing.module';
import { UsuarioFormComponent } from './components/usuario-form/usuario-form.component';
import { UsuarioListComponent } from './components/usuario-list/usuario-list.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   UsuarioHomeComponent,
   UsuarioFormComponent,
   UsuarioListComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    FormsModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    UsuarioRoutingModule
 ],
 exports:[
    UsuarioHomeComponent,
    UsuarioListComponent,
    UsuarioFormComponent
 ]
})
export class UsuarioModule { }
```

Can someone help me identify the error that I can't see..
I've looked everywhere for solutions, but I can't find anything about it

Comment: I'm not seeing the `usuario-edit.component` is imported in `UsarioModule`. Check for all component imports.

Comment: can you share `.ts` file of `usuario-edit.component`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the UsuarioEditComponent in your declarations:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   UsuarioHomeComponent,
   UsuarioFormComponent,
   UsuarioListComponent,
   UsuarioEditComponent
  ],

  imports: [
```